# How to reset counter (global variable) when one of the conditions changes

Tags: python, class

How to reset counter (global variable) when one of the conditions changes. Basically, increase the counter by 1 until "type_name" is "Bar" if it changes to something else set the counter to 0. How can this be achieved for multiple type_names'. Thank you.

```
type_name = "bar"
counter = 0

class Foo(object):
    """ 
    if type is different in the argument, reset counter to 0.
    Otherwise, increment the counter by 1.
    """

    def __init__(self, type_name):
        self.type_name = type_name
        self.counter = counter
        self.reset()

    def increment_counter(self):
        self.counter +=1

    def reset(self):
        if self.type_name != type_name:
            self.counter = 0


b = Foo("bar")
b.increment_counter()
b.increment_counter()
print b.counter


print "==============================="
c = Foo("taste")
c.reset()
print c.counter
c.increment_counter()
print c.counter


print "--------------------------"
d = Foo("bar")
d.increment_counter()
d.increment_counter()
print d.counter

print "--------------------------"
e = Foo("car")
e.increment_counter()
e.increment_counter()
print e.counter
```

Comment: I just realized I should not use increament_counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing here is that you're not modifying the global variable, but you're modifying the counter in the class (self.counter)
What you need to do is, in your reset function, change the global count, and not the one in that's a property of the class object.

```
def reset(self):
    global counter
    if self.type_name != type_name:
        counter = 0
```

Comment: (Modify in a similar fashion wherever you need to access the global variable)

Comment: Thank you. I updated code and this modification satisfies following use cases.

Comment: My pleasure. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Due to space limitation I am adding updated code here with one more use case.

```
type_name = "bar"
counter = 1

class Foo(object):
    """ 
    if type is different in the argument, reset counter to 0.
    Otherwise increment counter by 1.
    """

    def __init__(self, type_name):
        self.type_name = type_name
        self.counter = counter
        self.reset()


    def reset(self):
        global counter
        if self.type_name != type_name:
            counter = 1
        else:
            counter += 1

c = Foo("taste")
print c.counter

print "--------------------------"
d = Foo("bar")
print d.counter

print "--------------------------"
e = Foo("taste")
print e.counter

print "--------------------------"
new_instances = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    new_instances.append(Foo("bar"))
print new_instances
print new_instances[0].counter
print new_instances[8].counter
```